# How to debug program that pass argument to Main?

Tags: c#, console

I am writing a Console application that pass a string array of arguments to the Main. Using the F5 to debug would throw me an exception because I have not pass the arguments.

The way I debug/test the code where I can pass arguments is to build the solution and then run the .exe on the command prompt, but it's very inconvenient.

Is there a way to pass arguments to debug?

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475887/passing-command-line-parameters-with-vs-2010-c-sharp

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From within Visual Studio? Absolutely - go to the project's property designer, select the [Debug page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f97b3fb1(v=vs.100).aspx) and you can set the command line arguments, as well as the working directory. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ktzfy9w.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 26):

In Visual Studio right-click on the project name in Solution Explorer. Select Properties from the list.  Go to the Debug tab.  You can put your parameters in Command Line Arguments textbox.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05.aspx) has documentation on C# debugging. Basically, there is a "command line arguments" option in the project's property pages.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to enter command line arguments in the Project Settings dialog.

There's some info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05.aspx