# Calling a console app from the command line with string[] args

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a .NET Console app (very simple). The entry point takes the infamous string[] args argument. Does this mean that from a command line, I could call this app and pass in a single string as a parameter? If so, how?

Comment: Why is `string[] args` supposed to be infamous?

Comment: If you want to pass argument at the time of debugging refer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3644239/158207

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the `string[] args` is from the command line. The zeroth element is the first argument and so on. Please note unlike C or C++, `args[0]` doesn't contain the application name.

So if you do:

```
application.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Then:

```
args[0] = arg1
args[1] = arg2
args[2] = arg3
```

If you pass only one argument, that is available as `args[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

C:\application.exe string_parameter